# How to parametrize a parametrized function in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following pytest function, where GAMES_AVAILABLE is a dynamic list of different games that I want my code to test.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("game_ref", GAMES_AVAILABLE)
def test_all_games(game_ref):
    game_components = build_game_components(game_ref)
    available_players = determine_available_players(game_components)
    teams = create_player_teams(game_components['game'].number_of_players,available_players)
    for players in teams:
        if 'viz' in game_components:
            arena = Arena(players, game_components['game'], game_components['viz'])
        else:
            arena = Arena(players, game_components['game'])
        arena.playGames(2)
    return teams
```

With the following output

```
Testing started at 4:20 p.m. ...
Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8617.48)
Launching pytest with arguments /home/tue/PycharmProjects/Hive_nn/tests/test_all_games.py --no-header --no-summary -q in /home/tue/PycharmProjects/Hive_nn/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 3 items

test_all_games.py::test_all_games[game_ref0] 
test_all_games.py::test_all_games[game_ref1] 
test_all_games.py::test_all_games[game_ref2] 

======================== 3 passed, 3 warnings in 7.56s =========================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As it currently is, my code plays each game in all the possible configurations that the game can be played in, which is done dynamically depending on what functions have been implemented for a particular game.

Right now my code produces one test per game, however I would like for it to produce one test per team in each game and then run:

```
    if 'viz' in game_components:
        arena = Arena(players, game_components['game'], game_components['viz'])
    else:
        arena = Arena(players, game_components['game'])
    arena.playGames(2)
```

inside these new subtest.

But I am not sure how to do that?

Also I am very new to unit testing so if something seems strange or stupid in my code, it probably is, and I would appreciate any feedback about what to improve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate the list of parameters dynamically:

```
def team_games():
  for game_ref in GAMES_AVAILABLE:
    game_components = build_game_components(game_ref)
    available_players = determine_available_players(game_components)
    teams = create_player_teams(game_components['game'].number_of_players,available_players)
    for players in teams:
      # this can be simplified via get method if game_components is just a dict
      viz = game_components['viz'] if 'viz' in game_components else None
      yield players, game_components['game'], viz
      
@pytest.mark.parametrize("players,game,viz", team_games())
def test_all_games(players, game, viz):
  if viz:
    arena = Arena(players, game, viz)
  else:
    arena = Arena(players, game)
  arena.playGames(2)
```

You can even have complete arenas as a list of parameters. To do that modify `team_games` function so that it yield not tuples but Arena-s objects.

Comment: Of note: a drawback of this method is the generation is somewhat static and done at import time, so it can be difficult to configure using runtime information, or information which depends on configuration files or command-line parameters. However pytest also has a [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example) hook which, while a bit less sexy, and convenient, is a lot more flexible.